# Locust RPS value not coming correct #LOCUST # rpsissue

Tags: locust

we are getting very low Rps value according to the excepted result. Is there any way to control RPS value using python??

Answer (score 2):

In the Locust FAQ there is now a list of things to try when your throughput does not match your expectations (see https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/FAQ)

1. Increase the number of users. In order to fully utilize your target
   system you may need a lot of simultaneous users.
2. If response times are unexpectedly high and/or increasing as the number of users go
   up, then you have probably saturated the system you are testing and
   need to dig into why. **This is not really a Locust problem**, but here
   are some things you may want to check:

- resource utilization (e.g.
  CPU, memory)
- configuration (e.g. max threads for your web server)
- back end response times (e.g. DB)

3. If Locust is complaining about
   high CPU usage on its side

- Run Locust distributed to utilize
  multiple cores & multiple machines
- Try switching to FastHttpUser to
  reduce CPU usage

Answer (score 0):

You can using the min_wait & max_wait values. Set it to 0 and see if throughput increases.

```
    min_wait = 0
    max_wait = 0
    wait_time = between(min_wait, max_wait)
```

Comment: No difference with min_wait & max_wait values set to 0.